# Hibernate search cfg file error

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I'm new to hibernate search and I just started to make a sample search project using internet "how-to s". every thing seems fine except that when I try to run project I got the fallowing errors:

```
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.0.Final}
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(4) Element type "hibernate-configuration" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(6) Element type "session-factory" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(11) Element type "property" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(13) Element type "property" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(16) Element type "property" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(17) Element type "property" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(18) Element type "property" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(21) Element type "property" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(25) Element type "property" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(27) Element type "property" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(31) Element type "property" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(32) Element type "property" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(34) Element type "property" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(36) Element type "listener" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(37) Element type "listener" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(38) Element type "listener" must be declared.
Jan 7, 2012 4:10:41 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
ERROR: HHH000197: Error parsing XML: /hibernate.cfg.xml(40) Element type "mapping" must be declared.
```

but I declared all of the errors, here's my cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- 
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
         -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hsearchexample
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider</property>

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">
            ./searchTMP/indexes
        </property>

        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

        <listener type="post-insert" class="org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener"/> 
        <listener type="post-update" class="org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener"/> 
        <listener type="post-delete" class="org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener"/>

        <mapping class="ir.ehphan.search.Article" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I don't know what to do? and I don't seem to be finding answers using google... please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're  using hibernate 4 and because of that us should not define your listeners in hibernate.cfg.xml instead you should use an org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator which works based on "service discovery", according to [Hibernate Core Migration Guide : 4.0](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide40).
and you should change your

Answer (score 1):

According to the [dtd](http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd), it looks like there should be an event element that is child to your session-factory, and inside that event element you can have listener elements.